# Send data to a serial port via screen

Tags: gnu-screen, serial-port

I've connected to a serial port via `screen /dev/ttyACM0` and can read the input, but can't see the text I'm typing and nothing is being sent after I press enter.

Is it possible to send data from `screen`?

Comment: Having screen run `cu(1)` or `minicom` might offer a better interface than the raw device.

Comment: "Is it possible to send data from `screen`?"  I have often used `screen` to access serial devices on OS X, but not on (other) *ix machines.  You might try adding the `echo` parameter, something like `screen /dev/ttyACM0 38400,echo` or what have you for speed and other serial options.

Comment: You might need to use `control-j` intead of enter to end a line. it depends on what you have at the other end of the serial line.